# I want to strengthen my password in Laravel 6

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

I want to strengthen Laravel's standard password validation: `[A-Z] [a-z] [0-9].` I want to accept input with more than eight special characters and I need maximum support for Laravel Hash.

```
php artisan make:rule StrongPassword
```

What should I do after this?

Comment: That artisan command has nothing to do with how passwords are validated.

Comment: Is validator just not enough in your case?

Comment: @Jerodev What is this command used for?

Comment: @lkdhruw Is that so?
I want to check it just to be sure

Comment: @su3158 check this out https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#available-validation-rules

Comment: Laravel's default handling already permits more than eight special characters and has "maximum support" for hashing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add wathever validation rules you want in the Laravel `RegisterController`. Just update the rule for `password` with the extra limitations:

https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/Http/Controllers/Auth/RegisterController.php#L49

```
return Validator::make($data, [
    'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
    'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
    'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'], // <-- This one
]);
```

Comment: If you want to rewrite it at the time of resetting, you will need to change two places.

Comment: Correct, you will also have to change the rule there. You could also add the rule in a config or anywhere and reference that place so you don't have to change the rule twice every time a change is made.

Comment: What should I do to do that?